# How to integrate Spring MVC Javascript template engine with nunjucks?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, nashorn, nunjucks

This is my template engine config based on http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-mustache-js-template-example/

```
 @Bean
    public ScriptTemplateConfigurer configurer() {
        ScriptTemplateConfigurer configurer = new ScriptTemplateConfigurer();
        configurer.setEngineName("nashorn");
        configurer.setScripts(
                "/static/js/nunjucks.js", "/static/js/render.js");
        configurer.setRenderFunction("render");
        return configurer;
    }
```

//render.js file content

```
function render(template, model, url) {
    return nunjucks.render(template, toJsonObject(model));
}
```

and This exception occurred:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load script
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load script
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.script.ScriptTemplateView.loadScripts(ScriptTemplateView.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.script.ScriptTemplateView.createEngineFromName(ScriptTemplateView.java:277)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.script.ScriptTemplateView.initApplicationContext(ScriptTemplateView.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:399)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.applyLifecycleMethods(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:487)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1223)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined in <eval> at line number 9
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:467)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:451)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:403)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:399)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:150)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:249)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.script.ScriptTemplateView.loadScripts(ScriptTemplateView.java:289)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: <eval>:9 ReferenceError: "window" is not defined
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:319)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:291)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.__noSuchProperty__(Global.java:1432)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$2$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:9)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:640)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:228)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:446)
```

**So How I can provide or simulate window for nunjucks?**

Answer (score 0):

```
var window = {};
```

Should polyfill the window object.

[This repo was helpful to me for this](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-react-isomorphic)